# Why is skipping visibility checks only allowed for dynamic methods?

Tags: .net, clr, reflection.emit

I am porting code which uses `DynamicMethod`s extensively to allow for precompilation, for better cold startup performance. I noticed that `DynamicMethod`s can be JITted and executed with visibility checks skipped, which allows them to access private nested types, yet normal assemblies can not (or can't they? I don't see any obvious loader option). What is the rationale behind this design decision?

Comment: -unity, as this is not related to Microsoft Unity. You might read this blog post, http://davedewinter.com/2010/11/21/tip-22-dynamicmethods-in-partial-trust/ It does require certain permissions to do so. Therefore, if you want to restrict such attempts you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to wave my hands a bit answering this question, CAS is forever complicated.  The skipVisibility argument is relevant to trusted host applications that generate code that executes in a sandbox.  In such a case, it is not appropriate to perform checks when the method is generated since the execution environment is wrong.  It needs to happen when the method *executes* inside the sandbox.  Where it is subjected to the normal CAS checks performed by the sandbox.

Setting the argument to true in fact *adds* a permission demand for  ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess, required to have a shot at getting the method generated.

Topsy-turvy.  There's some background info in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384237.aspx), "Adding RestrictedMemberAccess to Sandboxed Domains" section.