# Skip visibility checks for dynamically generated methods without DynamicMethod

Tags: c#, cil, code-access-security, ilgenerator

This question is very similar to a two other questions see: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012196/why-is-skipping-visibility-checks-only-allowed-for-dynamic-methods), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431573/dynamicmethod-is-much-slower-than-compiled-il-function). However those are pretty out dated to say the least and I hope things have changed with .Net 5.

Now first up let me clarify the issue. With a simple example that tries to get the underlying array of a `List<int>.`

```cs
var method = new DynamicMethod("GetUnderlyingArray", typeof(int[]), new[] { typeof(List<int>) }, typeof(List<int>), true);

var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();

ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeof(List<int>).GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var arrayGetter = (Func<List<int>, int[]>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<List<int>, int[]>));
```

This works perfectly fine as I am able to tell the `DynamicMethod` to skip the visibility checks (even though it works as well, when the last parameter of the `DynamicMethod` constructor `true` is removed).

However, when I am trying to do the same with the example down below, it will throw a `FieldAccessException`.

```cs
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("Example");
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var dynamicModule = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

var type = dynamicModule.DefineType("GetUnderlyingArrayClass");

var method = type.DefineMethod("GetUnderlyingArray", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int[]), new[] { typeof(List<int>) });

var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeof(List<int>).GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

type.CreateType();

var arrayGetter = (Func<List<int>, int[]>)type.GetMethod("GetUnderlyingArray").CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<List<int>, int[]>));
```

> System.FieldAccessException: Attempt by method 'GetUnderlyingArrayClass.GetUnderlyingArray(System.Collections.Generic.List'1)' to access field 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1<System.Int32>._items' failed. + GetUnderlyingArrayClass.GetUnderlyingArray(List)

[Here is a .Net fiddle link with the code shown above.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sua9uX)

Now, one of the questions I mentioned points to the following attribute [`ReflectionPermissionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). However as it states on the documentation `Code Access Security is not supported or honored by the runtime.`. From what I understand, this basically means that .Net Core/.Net 5 [do not support CAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration).

Here is where I am getting confused. Setting the `skipVisibility` parameter to `true` or `false` doesn't actually matter. I'd assume that is due to the fact that I am running the code in a .Net 5 environment. However, if CAS is not supported on .Net 5, why am I still able to read out the private field?

The goal is obviously to access a private field/method from a dynamically generated method using the `DefineType`/`DefineMethod` API's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not able to explain why setting the `skipVisibility` parameter to `true`/`false` doesn't matter, however [PathogenDavid](https://github.com/PathogenDavid) over on the GitHub from the [csharp runtime discussion repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/48024#discussioncomment-352701) showed me a solution which was way easier than expected.

```cs
// Add IgnoresAccessChecksTo attribute
var ignoresAccessChecksTo = new CustomAttributeBuilder
(
    typeof(IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
    new object[] { typeof(List<>).Assembly.GetName().Name }
);

assemblyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(ignoresAccessChecksTo);
```

*See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YPkT7H) .Net Fiddle for a working example.*

As he said the `IgnoresAccessChecksTo` attribute is used to bypass the checks.

> The runtime understands the attribute, but it is not defined in the BCL so you have to define it yourself.